Recessed spotlights in converted loft in the UK
I want to install recessed spotlights in a bedroom in a converted loft and I am not sure whether it is ok to cut into the insulation that is above the plasterboard. Given that I need 6 or 8 spotlights, it is not clear to me whether it is ok to cut so many holes in the insulation. Can someone please advise whether there are any UK specific regulation on this topic or what is the best solution for the UK? The space between the insulation and the roof is not accessible without cutting a bigger hole in the plasterboard. I am thinking about cutting a 7cm hole in the plaster, then use a saw to cut a hole slighlty bigger than 7cm in the insulation (as required by the spotlight's instruction) and then install the spotlight in there with no extra cover (I want to install Philips Hue Centura recessed spotlight and the instructions specify that no cover should be used). Thank you.

If they specify no cover then that means the lights need adequate ventilation. That could be a volume 50cm by 50cm by 50cm of bigger per light.
There are lights in fittings designed to be covered by insulation - you need to consider your use.
